# How to Return Mocked Data Back With EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am going through [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) but it leaves me with so many questions.

1. Say I have this method

   public void Test(Guid userId)
   {
      var user = context.Users.First(x => x.Id == userId);
   }

How do I tell do I setup moq to return the correct user back? I have to make first a context full of users and I would like to keep the code maintainable so I would like to have one method that generates all the dummy context data.

1. Say I have this

   public void Test(Guid productId)
       {
          var user = context.Users.Products.First(x => x.Id == productId);
       }

In this case I am basically doing lazy loading. How do I populate Porducts? Do I just populate the Products context do I have to pouplate the Product context and in the Users context I have to generate all a collection of Products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming context implements an interface you would create a moq context and then use moq to setup the moq to return your desired results.

```
mockContext.Setup(m=> m.Products.First(Moq.It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(the product you want returned);
```

Comment: No if you look at the tutorial Context is not a interface, it is some different way than pre 6 EF.